# php7.3: Compile error with two traits that define the same property

Tags: php, symfony

I have this user class:

```php
class SuluUser extends BaseSuluUser implements SSOUserInterface, ResourceOwnerInterface, EquatableInterface
{
    use UserTrait;
    use SSOUserTrait {
        SSOUserTrait::__construct as __ssoConstruct;
        SSOUserTrait::setUserData as setUserDataTrait;
    }

    // ...
}
```

This are the traits:

```php
trait UserTrait
{
    // lot's of other fields

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $username = "";
}
```

And:

```php
trait SSOUserTrait
{
    // lots of other fields

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $username;

    // lots of getters and setters
}
```

And the BaseUser definition:

```
abstract class BaseUser extends ApiEntity implements UserInterface, Serializable, EquatableInterface
{
    /**
     * @var string
     * @Expose
     */
    protected $username;

    // lots of other fields
}
```

But it runs under php 7.3 into this fatal compile error:

> Fatal error: Sulu\Bundle\SecurityBundle\Entity\BaseUser and MyOrg\SsoBundle\Entity\UserTrait define the same property ($username) in the composition of MyOrgFrontendBundle\Entity\SuluUser. 
>   However, the definition differs and is considered incompatible.
>   Class was composed in sulu/src/MyOrgFrontendBundle/Entity/SuluUser.php on line 25

Are there any ideas how to fix this?

Thx a lot!

Comment: Please update your question with the trait classes.

Comment: @ChinLeung: Done!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to update one of the trait to have the property match the other trait.

For example, change in the `UserTrait`:

```
protected $username;
```

Instead of

```
protected $username = "";
```

Or do it the other way around, but both traits has to match.

Comment: Bam! Thanks a lot :)